# MySQL TRIM Issue

Tags: mysql

This is not working for me:

```
UPDATE emails SET address = TRIM(address);
```

> 0 rows affected. ( Query took 0.2440 sec )

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the table emails has any rows at all? try doing a SELECT to make sure, or adding WHERE 1=1 to your update clause (shouldn't really need that, but just in case)

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? What do you expect to happen? What data is in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe they didn't actually *need* trimming. From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.
>
> UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed.

In other words, they had no leading or trailing spaces.

If you really want to test this, use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emails;
UPDATE emails SET address = CONCAT(' ', address);
UPDATE emails SET address = TRIM(address);
```

(that first one is to check the possibility of an empty table).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that MySQL reports the correct number of rows, i.e., there was a total a zero rows changed by the update. That can happen if:

1. The table is empty.
2. There aren't any rows with leading or trailing whitespace (MySQL will not update a row if no column value change).